# ssrs - Forward pointing dependencies are not valid

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

In an existing SSRS 2008 r2, report, I am attempting to add a parameter called 'Customer_Category'. I am getting the following error message:
 The report paramter 'CustomerNumber' has a DefaultValue or a ValidVaue that depends on the report parameter 'Customer_Category'. Forward pointing dependencies are not valid.

I am trying to determine how to fix this error. The 'CustomerNumber' is a parameter value that is obtained by reading from a dataset. In this dataset there are existing other parameters called 'Customer_Type' and 'Customer_Preference'. Both of these parameters obtain there values from selections that the user makes when the SSRS report is executing. There are no default values.

I am trying to have the 'Customer_Category' be the same way where there are no default values and the user must select the parameter value when the report is executing. There should only be one value that the user can select from.

The new parameter called 'Customer_Category' is the last parameter in the list of parameters. Does the order of parameters make a difference? If so, how can I move the 'Customer_Category' parameter in front of the customer_number parameter?

Here is the sql that is used from obtaining a list of customers from the dataset for customer_number:-

```
SELECT Distinct CustomerNumber   
FROM BridgeUserCustomer  
WHERE
Type = @Customer_Type 
AND Preference = @Customer_Preference
AND Category = @Customer_Category
GROUP BY CustomerNumber
```

Would you tell me what is wrong and what I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, order of parameters makes a difference. What happens when you move `Customer_Category` to the top of the parameter list?

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

The [order of parameters in your IDE (Report Designer or Report Builder) matters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255258.aspx).

If you have a hierarchy of parameters (one level dependent on the other), the top-level parameter must appear first in the parameter list.

In SSRS these are referred to as [cascading parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255197.aspx).

## Solution

1. Open the Report Data tab
2. Expand the Parameters folder
3. Select a parameter and use the up/down arrows to adjust order

#### Report Designer

[image]

#### Report Builder

[image]